# Qual a diferença e as vantagens de SDL e Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, sdl

Queria saber quais as principais diferença entre  SDL e Unity3D a nível de performance e facilidade de uso e quando uma é mais indicada do que a outra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São coisas bem diferentes. O Unity é um engine completa. Ele te fornece praticamente tudo o que você precisa para fazer um jogo 2D ou 3D.

O SDL é uma biblioteca de baixo nível para acesso ao audio, keyboard, mouse e joystick. É focado mais em 2D, mas pode ser utilizado como ponto de partida para um engine próprio (usando OpenGL). Mas, dará mais trabalho pois o SDL não é uma engine.

Qual você deve usar vai depender do que você quer fazer, do tamanho da sua equipe e etc. Se você quer fazer um jogo indie 2D simples, o SDL resolve. Mas, se for 3D, utilizar SDL demandará muitas linhas de código até o primeiro modelo 3D estar na tela. Para fazer esse modelo 3D andar então...

No geral, acho Unity é mais fácil pois possui muitas ferramentas prontas, mas usar SDL ajuda a entender mais sobre o assunto (OpenGL, por exemplo), pelo fato de que você terá que configurar e implementar mais coisas.

Uma diferença importante entre elas é a licença. A SDL utiliza licença [zlib](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib_license.html), que é de uso livre.